# Procmail rules with regexp

Tags: procmail

here are my procmail recipes:

```
:0
* ^Subject: [JIRA] (EDRV-*) *$
.JIRA.edrive/new

:0
* ^Subject: [SPAM] *$
.SPAM/new

:0
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
.SPAM/new

:0
* .*
new
```

I want to put my messages with [JIRA] (EDRV-XXX) in the subject into the JIRA/edrive folder of the mailbox and messages marked with [SPAM] in the subject - into the SPAM folder.

But what I am getting now:

```
procmail: [8652] Sat Aug 27 19:08:19 2016
procmail: Assigning "SHELL=/bin/bash"
procmail: No match on "^Subject: [JIRA] (EDRV-*) *$"
procmail: No match on "^Subject: [SPAM] *$"
procmail: No match on "^X-Spam-Status: Yes"
procmail: Match on ".*"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=new/msg.qVktB"
procmail: Opening "new/msg.qVktB"
procmail: Acquiring kernel-lock
 Subject: [JIRA] (EDRV-100) xxxxxxx
  Folder: new/msg.qVktB><------><------><------><------><------><------>   2795
```

Where is a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic regex error. In order to match `[` or `(` literally, you have to escape them with a backslash.

The same applies to any regex metacharacter - `.`, `*`, `|`, etc.

Also, to match unconditionally, simply don't put any conditions.

I'm guessing you didn't really mean to only allow whitespace after the matches, so I took those out, too. If you wanted to say "anything", that's `.*` in regex, but there is no point in having a condition whitch matches anything.

```
:0
* ^Subject: \[JIRA] \(EDRV-.*\)
.JIRA.edrive/new

:0
* ^Subject: \[SPAM]
.SPAM/new

:0
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
.SPAM/new

:0
new
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to backslash escape regex characters that you want to match as literals.

It looks like you are using your mail is stored in Maildir format.  I don't know if you excluded the header or don't have one.  This will deliver files to the appropriate mail subdirectories.  It includes a log file so you can verify that the messages were correctly processed.

```
# .procmailrc - procmail configuration file

# Variable definitions
MAILDIR=$HOME/Maildir/
LOGFILE=$MAILDIR/procmail.log
DEFAULT=$MAILDIR
```

These rules should match the messages and deliver them to the `new` subfolder of the specified mailbox.

```
:0
* ^Subject: \[JIRA\] \(EDRV-.*\)
.JIRA.edrive/

:0
* ^Subject: \[SPAM\]
.SPAM/

:0
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
.SPAM/

# Anything left goes to inbox
```